# how to pass multiple entity of array HTTP post from Android to Rails 4

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The rails app has nested forms, its working in web and correctly save.But we have problem in the Android part, the values was not saving.

Here's the code in rails:

```
<%= nested_form_for @patient do |f| %>
<div class="title"> General Details </div>


<div class="name">
        <%= f.text_field :firstname, placeholder: 'FIRST NAME' %>
    <%= f.text_field :middlename, placeholder: 'MIDDLE NAME' %>
        <%= f.text_field :lastname, placeholder: 'LAST NAME' %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label "Immunization" %>
    <%= f.fields_for :ph_immunizations do |ph| %>
    <%= render "ph_immunization_fields", :f => ph %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "+ Add", f, :ph_immunizations %></p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

the partial:

```
<p>
  <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, value: @patient.id %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:immunization_id,Immunization.order(:description),:id,:description, 
              {include_blank: '', selected: field_value(:immunization_id) }, 
              class: "js-immunization js-select2", id: "immunization-select", "data-placeholder" => "Immunization") %>
  <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
</p>
```

Android:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://xxxxx/patients");

List<NameValuePair> immunizatioValuePairs = new ArrayList();

immunizatioValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ph_immunizations_attributes[1234567890123[immunization_id]]",  Integer.toString(1)));
immunizatioValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ph_immunizations_attributes[1234567890124[immunization_id]]",  Integer.toString(2)));
               immunizatioValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ph_immunizations_attributes[1234567890123[patient_id]]",  Integer.toString(98)));
               immunizatioValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ph_immunizations_attributes[1234567890124[patient_id]]",  Integer.toString(98)));

 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(immunizatioValuePairs));
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 InputStream responseContent = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Android's Logs in the server:

```
{"ph_immunizations_attributes"=>{"1234567890123"=>{"immunization_id"=>"1", "patient_id"=>"98"}, "1234567890124"=>{"immunization_id"=>"2", "patient_id"=>"98"}}}
```

Comment: This is just some template code, none of it is android specific. Please add your controller method and the form `params` you get from a browser and the "android". You could write them to the log file if you cannot see them already.

Comment: @Patru already posted the Android code. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the `parms` hash of the Android-post? Also the controller action (I guess it will be `create`) would be helpful.